# Deleting Objectid referenced to another collection in schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a field in my mongoose collection like so

```
MemberMatches: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Match'}],
```

I want to delete from this array the ObjectId when the user deletes a match from the Match collection. The ID of the match is coming from the react front end to my node backend and in my route here is what I have tried so far

```
    const deletedMatch = await MatchRegister.remove({_id: id}) (//remove the match from match collection)
        const member = await findamember(name) (find the member using member name from member collection)
        const newMatchArray1 = member.MemberMatches.filter(match => match.id !== id)
(filter the array based on the id coming from the front end)
        const deletedMember = Member.findOneAndUpdate({MemberName: name}, {$push: {MemberMatches: newMatchArray1}}) (command to rewrite the MemberMatches array back)
```

The last line however does not work. Can someone point me in the right direction please

Comment: Are you getting errors or cant see the updated result ??

Comment: figured it out dude. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. the command is $set instead of $push and now it works. Thanks